# Horizontally scrollable grid view

Tags: gridview, android-recyclerview, gridlayoutmanager, recyclerview-layout

I am designing an activity that should have a 2*2 grid.

There are other UI elements in the activity as well . The first half of the activity should take up this grid view.

This grid view has to be horizontally scrollable and on every scroll, activity should have a grid of 2*2.

I tried doing this using a recycler view and I set the layout of recycler view as follows

```
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(this,2,GridLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL,false));
```

With this the 2*2 grid spreads over two pages with two rows and not two columns

How can I get it to look like a grid of 2*2 that is horizontally scrollable?

I am new to android. Any help will be appreciated. Thank you

[image]

Comment: If you'd manage to have a visible two by two grid, but only two columns altogether, where do you want to scroll to horizontally?

Comment: When I swipe left or write I want to move to another view with the same grid but different contents. That is a grid of 2*@ should be visible when I scroll left or write but with different contents

Comment: Two `RecyclerView`s then? I think I don't understand. Can you provide a diagram?